# I am going to be editing the old questions forward. Any opinions?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have recently noticed that even the oldest questions have small errors in them. I think that this could be improved for future generations, both to improve readability and as a record.

First of all, I want the mods/reviewers to know this is going on, and that I will be correcting the following:

- Spelling
- Grammar
- Word choice
- Moving links to inline when they only appear once (Not a reason for editing by itself)

I, of course, don't want all of the rep, so I welcome other users to participate.

Also, I want input from a few mods **♦**   on this.

Comment: If I find a question that should have been deleted, should I post the link in the comments here so a mod can delete it?

Comment: Dropped off on post [#73](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-is-a-markov-chain-and-how-can-it-be-used-in-creating-artificial-intelligenc/73#73). Will resume as soon as my review queue has been cleared considerably.

Comment: I've been working my way through, and approving.  Thanks for taking the time to do some house cleaning!  The "action-recognition" tag need some work--not sure of the meaning...  (So far, everything else looks good.)

Comment: @DukeZhou thanks! My only worry is that others will not participate.

Comment: Picking up on post [#73](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-is-a-markov-chain-and-how-can-it-be-used-in-creating-artificial-intelligenc/73#73)

Comment: Dropped off on post [#4051](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-is-it-possible-that-deep-neural-networks-are-so-easily-fooled/4051#4051). Review queue bottle up. I hope you stay with me for these first few times, but I have been told you are permitted more edits in the queue the more you have approved.

Comment: Picking up on post [#4051](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-is-it-possible-that-deep-neural-networks-are-so-easily-fooled/4051#4051). Some of the queue was cleared.

Comment: Dropping off on post [#4011](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/94/what-is-the-significance-of-weights-in-a-feedforward-neural-network/4011#4011). Review Queue bottled up.

Comment: IMO, moving links which are in Markdown end-of-text format into being inline is counterproductive. The tools which exist for editing on SE are designed to put links in end-of-text format. Moving them inline may make it harder for the OP to edit their post, if they choose to do so. IMO, these should generally be left in the format in which they already exist in the post. This is similar to changing the indenting of code from one valid, common format to another valid, common format, just because you prefer it. OTOH, if the links are actually malformed/non-working, then they should be corrected.

Comment: @Makyen I had decided with another mod that I would leave them in the footer if there were more than 3 links. I apologize for the fact that I did not post this here, but that is what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds good to me.

A couple things to keep in mind: Especially when submitting suggested edits, please make sure to fix *all* problems with the post — this saves reviewer time and minimizes bumps. I'm not entirely certain what you mean by "moving links to inline when they only appear once," but if you're referring to the Markdown inline link style (as opposed to footnote style), please submit only edits that make improvements to the rendered post. Cleaning up the Markdown in the process of making helpful visual changes is good, though. Starting from the oldest posts and proceeding to the newest is a good idea because it keeps newer content nearer the top of the front page.

Thanks for helping improve AI.SE!

Comment: I do my best. Also, if you could look at even a few of my edits, it would help a lot.

Comment: @Pheo Just be understanding that the mods, like yourself, are donating their time, and new questions and, where available time is limited, answers have to take priority.

Comment: @DukeZhou I appreciate the time you guys have taken, also.

Comment: @BenN Thanks for taking some of your time to work on my queue. I can't wait until I have full edit privs though, so I could not bother you guys as much with the queue:P

Comment: @BenN I am going to postpone this project, until I have edit privs. I might do 2 or 3 a day, but thats it for now.